# Managing SSL certs for a multi-tenant website

Tags: ssl, hosting, multi-tenant

We have a multi-tenant website where we use a wildcard SSL cert to give people a subdomain to our site. Some of our customers would like to use their own domain, but I'm concerned about how we would manage each customer's certificate as our business grows. Currently the certificate resides on the web server, which means loading all of the certs to each web server as we add them.

I'm aware we could introduce a dedicated SSL device in front of the web servers, but are there other options to improve the management of these certificates?

Comment: Do you realise that each domain with an SSL cert will need it's own IP address?

Comment: At least until http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication support is wide-spread.

Comment: Thanks for the information on Server Name Indication. I wasn't aware of it. Unfortunately, we still have too many users on XP where it does not look like it is supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a Microsoft Technical Evangelist and one of my partners had exactly the same challenge.

I have created a sample source code that automates and manages SSL certificates for multiple domain bindings using a new IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012) feature called SNI, which is a kind of SSL hostheaders.

All you will need to do is to reuse my code (it's quite simple) and upload your custom SSL certificates to the blob storage, or you can write your own provider to fetch custom domains and certificates from your database.

I have posted a detailed explanation and a sample "plug & play" source-code at:
http://www.vic.ms/microsoft/windows-azure/multiples-ssl-certificates-on-windows-azure-cloud-services/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I believe I still don't have a viable answer for how to support Windows XP users who are on IE8 though. Has that been true of your own testing?

Comment: Honestly, my partners and I didn't even bother to check whether it was working on XP, because their main audience doesn't use Windows XP anymore...

Comment: I'm going to mark this answer as accepted. I think that with long term support for XP ending in less than a year, XP users do not need to be part of the solution. Thanks for following up!

Answer (score 0):

You could make your clients deal with their own certificates and make them run there own https site. They can serve a page containing a single frame with your content (over https). The users will see their domain and their certificate and the browser will load the frame without complaining as long as the frame contents are also loaded over a valid https connection. I created a quick an dirty [test page](https://d6.nl/tst.html) so you can see it in action.

This solution will 'break' the address bar as it will keep the url of the page containing the frame. Depending on the type of site you're running this might be a showstopper.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think that the loss of a usable address would make this untenable for our customers.